# MYSQL concatenating and comparing in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I have a relatively simple problem I'm trying to solve. I have two tables. One has a "first" name and a "last" name field, while the second has simply a "name" field with the first and last name together. I'm trying to match records with the same name and update a field called "code" from the 1st to the 2nd table. However, I know I can use the concat() function, but I keep getting an error when comparing. Here's what I've got:

```
    UPDATE managers
    SET managers.company_code = (
    SELECT oldManagers.Code
    FROM oldManagers
    WHERE oldManagers.name=CONCAT(managers.first, " ", managers.last)
);
```

I get this error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
UPDATE managers, oldManagers
SET managers.company_code = oldManagers.Code
WHERE oldManagers.name = CONCAT(managers.first, " ", managers.last)
```

It will update the the field `company_code` of the `managers` table to the value of the `oldManagers.Code` based on you `where` clause.

Comment: Hmm, the error resolves, but none of the rows are being updated

Comment: are you sure there are relevant rows?

Comment: Got it! Turns out one of the tables hadn't been trimmed, their were hidden characters. thanks for the help!